# RegEx for line with just just one @ symbol without any ; and , symbols

Tags: regex, validation, email, symbols

I searched a log of times for such regular expression in Google without success.

The requirements are:

1. There must be only one occurrence of `@` symbol on the line
2. The line must not contain any `;` or `,` symbols

A valid line can be: `personal@email.cozz (Tom Jones)`

Comment: Post at least 3-4 sample inputs, and also the code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your input is a list of emails.

You can use: /^[^@,;]+@[^@,;]+$/

Explanation:
The two "[^@,;]+" ensure that there aren't any @ before and after the only one allowed.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer